# reorder the following efficiencies from smallest to largest

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, complexity-theory

reorder the following efficiencies from smallest to largest

1- nlogn

2-n+n^2+n^3

3-24

4-n^0.5

I knew that the smallest is 24 and largest n+n^2+n^3 
but im confused between "4-n^0.5" and "1- nlogn"

Comment: Try something simpler: n^0.5 versus n.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n^0.5)` is the same as `O(sqrt(n))`, and hence it will be always lesser than O(n).

`O(nlogn)` on the other hand will be always greater than `O(n)`.

`24` is a costant, so it can be treated as simply `O(1)`.

Regarding `n+n^2+n^3`, you are correct that it is lease efficient, because it will translate into O(n^3).

Hence the correct order would be

```
3 < 4 < 1 < 2
```